# Catch by pattern except strings which ends with two special characters in a row

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to create a Go regex that catch strings by a specific pattern, except strings that end with 2 special characters in a row, and don't want to use lookahead, is it possible?

This is the pattern I have so far `(?:[a-zA-Z]+.)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}`.

For example, give this string: `test.testing.com. test2.net.*`

I would like to catch `test.testing.com` but **not** `test2.net`

Answer (score 0):

You may capture that part with

```golang
\b([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*)\b(?:.?$|[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]|[^[:punct:]][[:punct:]])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC9mnf/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*)`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `.?$` - any optional single char (other than line break) and end of string
  - `|` - or
  - `[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]` - a punctuation and a non-punctuation char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^[:punct:]][[:punct:]]` - a non-punctuation and a punctuation char
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

See a [Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/Drh2kN9RO5W):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    markdownRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`\b([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*)\b(?:.?$|[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]|[^[:punct:]][[:punct:]])`)
    str := `test.testing.com. test2.net.*`
    for _, result := range markdownRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", result[1])
    }
}
// => test.testing.com
```